# .NET Maui - ios simulator crashes on clicking entry field

Tags: ios, .net, maui

Been working on a .NET MAUI app for a bit and finally bought myself a MacBook Pro to start targeting iOS devices.  I did the pair to mac and the first time it actually worked...but it has been flakey.  Anyway, I brought up my app in an iOS simulator and it comes up, but then as soon as I click into any entry fields, the app crashes.

I'm using the latest of everything, including MacOS and XCode.

Anybody else have this happen?

Comment: What exception causes the crash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm using the latest of everything, including MacOS and XCode.

This is exactly the issue! Xcode 15.3 is not supported right now as also indicated by [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/21057) which is pinned on the .NET MAUI repository.

Downgrade to Xcode 15.2 for now (you could use Xcodes for that) to keep developing without issues until the bindings for the latest iOS SDK version are ready.

Or the other way around: use Xcode 15.3 but install the iOS 17.2 Simulators which should work as well, or physical devices with an older iOS version.

In the linked issue is also a workaround mentioned for working with Xcode 15.3 and iOS 17.4.

Comment: Thanks for the information as I've been using MAUI for about 4 months, but just tried iOS for the first time on a new MacBook Pro.   I will say, I got it to work, but this thing is flaky as hell!  I tried to basically uninstall all Xcode and reinstall 15.2.  Seems to have helped.

The connection works about half the time, and I did note that if my app crashes, I basically have to reboot both computers to get the simulator back.  I was hoping this would be better.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this today starting up an emulator with 17.4 and thought I broke something.

Interestingly, I am still using XCode 15.3 but staying away from running emulators with 17.4 and this seems to be working. Note: I haven't testing anything but iPhone 14 Pro Max iOS 16. ‍♂️